# How can I set the width for a text area attached by the autoSuggest plug-in for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

I found a great plug-in for doing Auto-Complete with Javascript called AutoSuggest thanks to this Stack Overflow post:

[plugin to separate tags (like the stackoverflow's input tags interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031162/plugin-to-separate-tags-like-the-stackoverflows-input-tags-interface)

Here is the link to the plug-in author's page:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

The autoSuggest plug-in is setting the width of the **input** box (type="text") for entering queries to 1000px, much wider than I want.  It is somehow overridding the width set in the input box style property in the document HTML:

```
<div NAME="divAutoSuggest" ID="divAutoSuggest">
        <input type="text" NAME="editQuery2" ID="editQuery2" wrap="soft" style="margin-left:5px;width:600px;" title="Enter your search query here using plain English"></input>
</div>
```

I also tried using the *cols* attribute in the input box definition but that was ignored too.  I found this other Stack Overflow post that talked about intercepting the width setting during the *open* event, but the example was for the *autocomplete* plug-in and not autoSuggest:

[Changing width of jquery-ui autocomplete widgets individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607164/changing-width-of-jqueryui-autocomplete-widgets-individually)

I tried it anyways using this code:

```
$(document).ready
(
function() 
{
    // Put jQuery related initialization code that must occur after the document is ready here.

    $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest
    (
        data.items, 
        {
            selectedItemProp: "name", 
            searchObjProps: "name",
            startText: "Enter Evernote tags here...",
            open: function(event, ui) 
            {
                $(this).autoSuggest("widget").css
                (
                    {
                        "width": 600
                    }
                );
            }
        } // data. items
    ); // $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest
} // function() 
); // $(document).ready
```

But that did not work either.  can anyone tell me how to set the width of the input box?  Note I am not talking about the drop-down box with the auto-complete entries, I am referring to the primary input area where you type the text that triggers the auto-complete drop-down box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the width for the [AutoSuggest jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin), you need to search for `ul.as-selections` in the CSS that came with it and define your width:

**CSS**

```
ul.as-selections {
  ...
  width: 400px; // define your width
  ...
}
```

---

If you haven't changed the original CSS, It's like this:

**CSS ORIGINAL DECLARATIONS** <sup>for `ul.as-selections`</sup>

```
ul.as-selections {
 list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #888;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #888;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Is there any way to find out in advance what the minimum width autoSuggest deems necessary based on the auto-complete values?  I noticed when trying your solution that if I set the width too small, below some value unknown to me, a horizontal scroll bar appeared beneath the input box.  Once I exceeded that unknown value the horizontal bar disappeared.

Comment: Seems hard go "guess" the width of contents to come. And I suspect that may vary and change with time, the only thing I can suggest you is to set `overflow-x:hidden;` to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from showing up! _(just tested and it works fine)_

Comment: On another topic, since this did solve your issue, please tick the answer as correct to close this topic!