# jQuery Autocomplete - cannot find where the width is being set on the suggestions div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet, client-side

I am using jQuery Autocomplete - it all works fine however I would like to amend the width, currently in Firebug the width is set to 268px, but I want this to be 520px.

I cannot see where the width is being set to 268px in the stylesheet, trying to override the 'autocomplete-suggestions' with an !important doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to set this width from 268px to 520px?

```
<div id="appendTo">
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions" style="position: absolute; width: 268px; max-height: 300px; z-index: 9999;">
```

Existing CSS

```
.autocomplete-suggestions {
    background-color: #79BE28;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px #CCCCCC;
    max-height: 650px !important;
    width: 520px !important;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions .autocomplete-suggestion {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions .autocomplete-suggestion:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions .autocomplete-suggestion strong {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.autocomplete-suggestion {
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially do it like this. (As seen in [Changing width of jquery-ui autocomplete widgets individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607164/changing-width-of-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widgets-individually))

```
$('#input').autocomplete({  
   source: mysource,   
   open: function() { $('#autocomplete-suggestions').width(520) }  
});
```

Comment: My original code seems to work now?!? Must have been some weird browser caching problem, although I prefer the solution you have provided thanks Andrew :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's set as inline CSS, you can't override it with a css stylescheet. You will have to change the value with js. Change or remove this inline css value after it has been setted by the jQuery

Try it during the jquery autocomplete event : `open( event, ui )`

```
$( ".autocomplete-suggestions" ).autocomplete({
  open: function( event, ui ) {
$('.autocomplete-suggestions .your-list-selector').css( 'width', '520px' );
}
});
```